# Increasing and Decreasing UI slider value by PLUS and MINUS sign

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to change the value of slider by clicking on + and - sign sitting beside the ui slider as following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/NCNA7/50

I tried to add a function like this

```
$(.PLUS).click(function(){
slide: function(event, ui) {
var currentVal = ui.value;
currentVal + 1;}
});
```

But it did not work! Can you please give me an idea how I can fix the issue?
Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$(".PLUS").click(function() {
    var value = $("#slider").slider("value")
        , step = $("#slider").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider").slider("value", value + step);
});

$(".MINUS").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider").slider("value")
        , step = $("#slider").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider").slider("value", value - step);        
});
```

Always be sure to quote your selectors (`".PLUS"`). Check out the [slider documentation](http://api.jquery.com/demos/slider) for the other methods that were used.

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QYuWQ/